# Changing the directory for print spool files in linux

Tags: printing, cups

The default location of print spool files is `/var/spool/cups` in Ubuntu 14.04. I tried to edit the `cups-files.conf` file which is located in `/etc/cups/` directory, but I'm unable to change the directory for the spool files. I want to know how I can change the location for spool files.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation suggests you change the RequestRoot option in the config file.  Did you try that?

> RequestRoot directory
>
> Specifies the directory that contains print jobs and other HTTP request data. The default is "/var/spool/cups".